# Using inline if operator in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I am trying to implement a toggle between absolute and variable line numbering in vim and I'd like to do as a one liner instead of writing an if function.

My current code is:

```
nnoremap <F4> :( &rnu == 1 ? "set nu" : "set rnu" )<CR>
```

which does not work; anybody knows how can I make it work?

Comment: See also: "[vim : toggle number with relativenumber](http://superuser.com/q/339593)".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I would accomplish this:

```
:nnoremap <f4> :setl <c-r>=&nu ? "rnu" : "nu"<cr><cr>
```

The longer version that is probably a little more clear for the future Googlers:

```
:nnoremap <f4> :setlocal <c-r>=&number ? "relativenumber" : "number"<cr><cr>
```

The `<C-r>=` tells vim to use the expression register to evaluate the rest of the line as vim commands.  The trailing double `<cr>` is required because the first one evaluates the expression and the second one executes the `:setlocal` command.

Comment: Update: The behaviour of `'number'` and `'relativenumber'` has changed in Vim 7.3.1115. Toggling now works a little differently, see my answer at http://superuser.com/a/604625.